# Laplace equation on semidisk

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

I am interested in the solution of the following boundary value problem on the semidisk $D=\{(r,\theta): 0<r<1, 0<\theta<\pi\}$: $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 \mbox{ in } D, $$ $$u(1,\theta)=0 \mbox{ for } 0<\theta<\pi$$ and $$u(x,0)=f(x) \mbox{ for } -1<x<1$$ where $f(x)$ is a given function. I don't see if separation of variables could work, or maybe I need more advanced method.

Comment: Wild idea right off the bat: Perhaps you can map the problem conformally to a disk (Möbius to a quadrant, $z \mapsto z^2$ to a half plane, Möbius from there to a disk) and solve it there?

Comment: This seems to work. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to use polar coordinates,  so you seek the solution:

$u(x,y)=u(r(x,y),\theta(x,y))=R(r)\Theta (\theta)$ (here we use separation of variables)

If you follow the calculations through, you will be lead to a cauchy euler equation.

Can you take it from here?

Also $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $\tan\theta=\frac { y } { x}$.

Comment: This works for disk. But I have a semi disk here.

Comment: It also works for a semi disk (I have done a similar question before)

Comment: The similar question you have done is probably for $u(1,\theta)=f(\theta), u(x,0)=0$. I know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Following Hans Lundmark's suggestion, we compose 3 maps: $\frac{z+1}{1-z}$, $z^2$, $\frac{-i+z}{i+z}$, to get the map
$$h(z)=\frac{(1+z)^2-i(1-z)^2}{(1+z)^2+i(1-z)^2}$$
which maps the upper boundary of the semidisk to the upper boundary of the unit disk, and the lower line segment of the semidisk to the lower boundary of the unit disk.

Now we solve the problem on the unit disk, with $g(\theta)=0$ on the upper semicircle, and $$g(\theta)=f\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-\tan(\theta/2)}}{1+\sqrt{-\tan(\theta/2)}}\right)$$
on the lower semicircle. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758724/inverse-of-the-function-frac1x2-i1-x21x2i1-x2/759178#759178).
But finding Fourier coefficients of $g$ seems to be formidable even if $f$ is simple. So I am not sure if this approach is the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark. What do you think? Thanks.