# Inverse of the function $\frac{(1+x)^2-i(1-x)^2}{(1+x)^2+i(1-x)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

It can be proved that the function $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $$f(x)=\frac{(1+x)^2-i(1-x)^2}{(1+x)^2+i(1-x)^2}$$ maps the interval $[-1,1]$ one to one onto the lower part of the unit circle. Does anyone have an explicit formula for the inverse function $f^{-1}(\theta)=?, -\pi<\theta<0$? It seems unlikely, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\theta$ that corresponds to $x$ is $$\theta=-2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2,$$
so $$\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\sqrt{-\tan (\theta/2)}.$$
Solving for $x$ we get $$ x=f^{-1}(\theta)=\frac{1-\sqrt{-\tan (\theta/2)}}{1+\sqrt{-\tan (\theta/2)}}, -\pi<\theta<0.$$